# UIView's height constraints break child view's height constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, inputaccessoryview

I have a really simple setup that I can't get to do what I want.

I'm trying to add an `inputAccessoryView`.

For the `inputAccessoryView` I have a `UIView` (**ViewA**) with a subview (**ViewB**). **ViewB** is fixed to all edges of **ViewA**. **ViewB** has a fixed height, which needs to be the height of both **ViewA** and **ViewB**.

**ViewA**'s isn't set by me, but is `0` which breaks the height of **ViewB** (set to 42).

**ViewA** is added as a subview on a `UIViewController`'s view and fixed to the bottom and both the leading and trailing edges (so width of **ViewA** and **ViewB** should be that of the UIViewController's view, which it is).

Here's the code I have:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    let viewB = UIView()
    addSubview(viewB)

    viewB.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    viewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    viewB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    viewB.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    viewB.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    viewB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 42).isActive = true
}
```

Which results in the following error:

```
2017-12-02 15:44:59.150228-0800 Ping[37511:5808904] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000283b60 h=--& v=--& MyApp.ViewA:0x7fe606511360.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000282030 UIView:0x7fe606511550.height == 42   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000281d60 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7fe606511550]   (active, names: '|':MyApp.ViewA:0x7fe606511360 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000281ef0 UIView:0x7fe606511550.bottom == MyApp.ViewA:0x7fe606511360.bottom   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000282030 UIView:0x7fe606511550.height == 42   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

**ViewA** has a pretty simple setup:

```
extension MessageViewController {

    open override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    open override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return messageInputView
    }

}
```

Why does **ViewA** height that I never set break the constraint that I setup?

Comment: @RuslanSerebriakov I've updated the code above

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution is to disable the Autoresizing Mask for **ViewA**:

```
viewA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Since you are laying it out with the constraints. Now it tries to set your ViewA's height to 0 which causes the problem.

Comment: I've added some more details. It's an `inputAccessoryView`, but even adding it as a regular subview results in width and vertical position being ambiguous because the height.

Comment: so is it intended that viewA has a height 0 (like because for the current case it should be hidden)?

Comment: ViewA should be the size that its subviews are set to.

Comment: can you share your configuration of messageInputView ?